# Can society exist without hierarchy?

Tags: political-philosophy, society, sociology, human-condition, animals

If we consider "a society" to be a group of individuals within the same species who cooperate for the benefit of the group as a whole, then it is reasonable to say that all human societies are hierarchical to some degree.

Several well known philosophies aspire to a society entirely without hierarchy. 
However looking at nature for inspiration doesn't help much as it seems that all social animals from mammals, to birds, to fish to insects have a hierarchical social structure. From an evolutionary perspective it can be argued that this makes sense as without a social structure aggression and violence is much more likely in order to assert access to food and breeding rights, sacrificing rank in society for a low risk albeit slightly reduced access to food and mates could therefore be a sensible trade off. In addition leadership prevents group fragmentation and subsequent vulnerability to predators.

The question is therefore is hierarchy inherent to and/or necessary for the existence of Society?

Comment: When you talk about "hierarchical (social) structure", are you referring to a specific mathematical structure? Is it one of [preorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder), [total preorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_preorder) or [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)?

Comment: This question sounds more like a discussion opener than a Stack Exchange question, if I understand the rules correctly.  You can ask for books and papers about social philosophy, but I doubt we'll find any consensus here.

Comment: If society is a mutual agreement then anything can be. You underestimate possibilities though. There can be hierarchical societies which are totally fare. For example the rotating hierarchy. Every member must take every place in hierarchy for some time. Then start over.

Comment: @Keven Holmes, that's the problem with philosophy.stackexchange. The entire Stackexchange family of sites is designed for questions to be answered. In philosophy none of the questions ever get answered, just discussed. I assume people here have noted this before.

Comment: @Kevin Holmes yes you're right it was really a discussion opener, I don't think this is really a question that can be definitively answered. Are you supposed to only answer answerable questionsas in "where can I find research on the need for hierarchy in society"?

Comment: From a management perspective, yes. 99% of the current managers can be replaced by an automated task transmission system and automated result reporting. From other points of view, yes, it can exists but it will not. Once they got the power, they will never give it up.

Comment: I would question the premise that several philosophies aspire a society without hierarchical structure. Many do aspire a society where hierarchy is shaped by individual ability instead of (inherited) material or political power. I do not know a single author arguing for a (permanent) loss of societal hierarchies, even if pop culture and some self-declared adherents do (falsely) sell eg. communism or anarchism that way.

Comment: Hierarchies introduce unnatural, arbitrary standards of values that unnecessarily hamper and condition the natural growth of a human being.

Answer (score 2):

Anthropologist David Graeber did his doctoral work on Madagascar, the 2nd to last large landmass to become permanently inhabited by humans, and gave this great talk about [what we can learn about the 'state of nature'](https://youtu.be/_0oOod0nu3I) from it. He contends that highly unequal societies, eg those with slaves, are  unstable & when they dissolve cultural tactics emerge to resist a return to that - that what we see Native American cultures is not simply human 'instincts' manifesting, but the results of long tussles between more & less violent & hierarchial groups, largely settled in the absence of new technologies entering the scene, in favour of minimal hierarchy.

Exactly what is meant by hierarchy is crucial. Graeber says in Native American cultures being a chief meant working harder, getting up earlier every day & doing more, but above all, being pursuasive. So is that hierarchy?

Gobekli Tepe is thought to be the first known megalithic structure, & built by hunter-gatherers - archaeologists suggest it implies there *must* have been a hierarchy there, to build it. I suspect that argument relates to their definitions, and things like division of labour.

Economists Pickett & Wilkinson wrote 'The Spirit Level: Why More Equal Societies Almost Always Do Better' and 'The Inner Level: How More Equal Societies Reduce Stress, Restore Sanity and Improve Everyone's Well-Being'. They make a detailed numbers-based argument about the corrosive effects of inequality, relating it to things like crime & security costs, and multiple measures of internal wellbeing, include haming the wealthy & elite where inequality is still also a net-negative (Markovits analyses that specific issue in more depth in [The Meritocracy Trap](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2019/09/meritocracys-miserable-winners/594760/)).

How we perceive human nature nature will have a big impact. Hobbes who lived through the English Civil war, saw a tyrant as essential to stop 'the war of all against all'. Rousseau saw the state of nature as the ideal, and so city living & it's discontents as intrinsically corrupting - he got to live a largely charmed life avoiding consequences of his actions though, like by sending more than half a dozen illegitimate children to the orphanage.

Jonathan Haidt's research has shown links between threat-perception during key formative years, teens to about 25 when our prefrontal cortex is being fine-tuned, to attitudes that shape our whole lives. The schism between Baby Boomers & the World War generation is particularly notable - & Boomer optimism went with the greatest increase in equality ever in human history.

The Dunbar Number indicates humans evolved for social group sizes of around 150. This is supported by archeology, the Domesday Book village sizes, the number of faces we can remember, & other indications. Cities are very modern in evolutionary terms, linked directly to animal domestications & emergence of writing. Very little genetic change has happened in that time. Their utility seems to be about the *memetic*. Our eusociality, our hive-like behaviour, seems to link to this scale, with reproduction inequality of that order.

Chimpanzees do not have single strongest individuals, like gorillas. Males have to firm a coalition, with substantial grooming services & preferential treatment of supporters. Bonobos, our closest relatives, have greatly extended social grooming to diffuse tensions, they have frequent sex. Humans are not that like either group. Was discussing recently the role of humour in diffusing tensions, allowing feelings to be expressed and tensions relieved in a context defined as play, & this seems like it might be an under-recognised human advantage - 'good sense of humour' was the top requested trait in posting of romance adverts in singles sections of newspapers, suggesting after physical traits it is of uniquely high desirability.

Anarcho-syndicalism in Spanish Civil War-era Catalonia was very successful in running the economy and militarily, Franco arguably only won because of Nazi support.

I like this comic strip framing very very much:

[image: Wondermark]

Define your terms, pick your discourse, state what you wish to determine specifically, to reach a settled answer. But I hope here are some alternative perspectives you might not have encountered that play against the seeming 'default' of Jordan Peterson-esque appeals-to-nature (lobsters do it so we must), or Randian championing of the status quo untethered from any research whatsoever.

Comment: "*humans evolved for social group sizes of around 150.*" -- less than that, probably (< 100 on average), and it wasn't a "social group", it was a family

Comment: "*like this comic strip framing very very much*" -- and I get it... I understand what you are struggling with, because that same issue effectively defined our "civilization" since the Bronze Age collapse 3,000 years ago -- you don't have no concept of truth*! <== that is NOT to say you don't know what IS true -- of course you do, everyone does! But, you don't know *what it means* to be true, what makes something true.

Comment: ... and if you ask how could we even survive for millennia without something as basic, as fundamental as *truth*? -- I would say it has definitely been a challenge. Not a single day without war. Our lives have been defined by never-ending violence and oppression, and you know what is funny? -- *none of it could be justified rationally*. It benefited no one in terms of happiness. It only added to everyone's misery, made everyone suffer. <== that's the price for living without truth, for not *seeing* where one is going, for not *knowing* what one is doing.

Comment: 150, as based on *evidence*, which you should try considering sometime https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunbar%27s_number Are you even conscious of how you have defined truth, and the implicit assumptions you have made, and their consequences? You aren't even ready to debate the topic.

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/54847/is-there-a-single-definition-of-truth

Comment: Oh please... From your links, quoting Dunbar: "In dispersed societies... group sizes should be smaller". And they were, google "[hunter gatherer tribe size](https://www.google.com/search?q=hunter+gatherer+tribe+size&oq=hunter+gatherer+tribe+size)". The top answer to the truth question opens with "*The concept of truth is one of the head-spinners of philosophy*" <== exactly... I merely pointed out, that having a lively debate on such a subject is not without consequences either.

Comment: My next obvious question, then -- don't you think that there are more important issues at stake here, other than simply proving me wrong? And if not -- why not?

Comment: @YuriAlexandrovich: - _^ You are quibbling in response to my post.. It's up to you to make your case there is some important difference between family & tribe. I am using that to argue status differentiation beyond that scale seems to not be something we evolved with, so it's irrelevant to my case. You seem to have assumed there is a single objective Truth, failure to perceive or accept which is some kind of mental illness, or involves being a non-sentient algorithm somehow. And I just don't accept that version of what truth means, and don't think it can stand up to even minimal scrutiny.

Comment: ok, i'll start -- in what sense it is "truth", if it's *not* objective?

Comment: @YuriAlexandrovich: comments are not the place for extended debate. Perhaps post an answer to the the thread I posted a link to. I don't believe in objectivity, I see it as only reified intersubjectivity. It is an illusion, because no one experiences it. There is only the compound of subjective experiences.

Comment: Well, I don't know if I want to create an answer just to ask "why intersubjectivity?" 'Cause you absolutely did experience the objective reality -- we all do, every time we interact with others -- which we only can, *because* we share the same reality! Except that you, instead of recognizing it as such, suggest it must be "intersubjectivity", whatever that means...

Comment: btw, feel free check out my answer to about the nature qualia -- [it covers objectivity as well](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/77518/47003)

Comment: @YuriAlexandrovich Please stop having off-topic discussions in comments. Feel free to discuss your marginal view in chat.

Comment: Upvoted just for the cartoon!

Answer (score 1):

Humans are always trying to gain as much control over the world and its resources as they can.  We are always obsessed with science and engineering in order to gain knowledge of our world, so that we can control it even further.  We even have social sciences to attempt to control our own species.

Humans will take any opportunity they can to gain more control over their natural environment, and other humans who form part of the environment are no exception.  If a human can control another human with limited repercussions, he will attempt to do so, either subtly or through a formal institution.

Because all humans are not made equal (I do not mean this as an ethical statement about human rights, but about the human genome), they will naturally compete for control of each other, and there will be a victor.  The victor will naturally dominate the others, simply because he can - and humans will never pass up an opportunity for further control of their available resources.

Comment: I think this is a good partial answer to the question, possibly because I asked the question badly! You seem to be saying that you think that humans will naturally try to dominate each otehr given the opportunity, which I pretty much agree with, however the question is more general than that and relates to society human or animal and whether hierarchy is necessary for it to function. Is society without any form of intra-group dominance something that can ever exist?

Comment: "Humans will take any opportunity they can to gain more control over their natural environment", but then why do people who believe in hierarchy-less society exist? E.g. I wouldn't take an opportunity to gain control over natural environment through hard force, therefore am I exception?

Comment: "Humans are always trying to gain as much control over the world and its resources as they can. " Is that justifiable? We have been modern humans for more than 100,000 years, but only hoarding more than we can possibly use in modern times. Many societies stayed largely the same for longer than continuous European civilisation has existed."because he can" Our social structure is not that of gorillas.

Answer (score 0):

As the examples you point out show societies do not exist without some form of social differentiation. Aristotle, for example, marked out five kind of political organisation - from monarchy to tyranny.

I'd be very surprised if any social philosophy in its mature form discounted social differentation of any kind. The question usually is to what extent and to what forms.

For example, ideally, all persons are equal before the law; which one can consider as an egalitarian concept - does not mean that there is no social differentiation; for then there are citizens (those who are under the law), judges (who apply the law), police (who enforce the law)  and prisoners (whose citizenship is curtailed).

Comment: Equal before the law is an absurdity in today's context. This is practically  now a lie. Laws are created by the ones in power to prevent the rest from getting too much power. While that, stealing a bread gives you more jail time than stealing millions of $ in many 'democratic' countries.

Comment: @overmind: Sure; unfortunately the finance-business lobby have far too much power as the recent financial crash only too clearly showed. The law, at that level, does not have enough teeth.

Answer (score 0):

Do cells have hierarchy (neurons, schwann cells, glial cells)? Do atoms have hierarchy (electrons, protons, neutrons, iron, copper)? Are these not natural occurring phenomena? Speaking as someone with limited sociological knowledge yet as someone with psychobio knowledge, the only societies which exist without hierarchy are basketball courts and soccer fields. A forward, defensive player, rebounder, goal tender are not hierarchical, they are "positions" the same way that a proton, neutron and electron are not hierarchical - but without their existence in the organism, it collapses. Hierarchy may change with the adjustment of the construct and the language itself - "positions" versus hierarchical "titles". I.e. a "King" or "president" is a hierarchical title, but an "Engineer" or "forward" or "coach" is not hierarchical - it is "positional" in a sense. In short terms, no one is higher than another on a baseball field (more skilled is a different story which is also arguably subjective at times) - but if we can agree that a baseball pitch, soccer pitch, or basketball court can be a platform for a society, there is no hierarchy there. I invite thoughts.

Comment: "without hierarchy are basketball courts and soccer fields" What about star strikers? Magi Johnson's success on court made him hugely rich, differentiating him even on court.

Answer (score 0):

If all individuals think the same, there's no need of a leader, and there's no possibility of a hierarchy. But expecting all individuals to think identically is utopic.

**Hierarchy is the result of natural differences**. When two individuals are different in some matter, one tends to lead the action. The differences could be physical or mental (in fact, depending on the domain, typical leaders are either strong or smart people).

So, the only way for hierarchical structures to disappear is if all individual are identical, which is impossible. In practice, different capabilities tend to result in hierarchies.

Some groups try to avoid hierarchies (the aymaras of the Andes live in extreme conditions, so they need to cooperate constantly, social structures tending to be more horizontal than those of western civilization groups), but the fact is that in spite of such ideal, implicit leaders will always raise, implying more power and effective hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a society exist without hierarchy?

Yes, absolutely! A *human* society can -- and should! -- have no power hierarchy. The fact that we routinely resort to imposing our will on others, is but a testament to our failure as human beings. No less.

Just think about it for a second. We share the same reality. We ourselves *are* a part of it. I would be hard-pressed to think of a valid statement that would not be *objectively* true or false.

*And if we disagree about something objective, it means one of us (at least) is **wrong**.*<sup>1</sup>

That, in turn, means we would want to get to the bottom of it ASAP! Because until we know exactly whose ideas were wrong *and in what way*, neither of us can be sure of the soundness of choices -- the past, or the future ones!<sup>2, 3</sup>

In other words, save different personal tastes,<sup>4</sup> *we should never **be** in disagreement about anything*! -- much less so about something important.

That simply leaves no room for having conflicts, much less for going through all the troubles of imposing one's will on the others. Not just the hierarchy of, but the very concept of power makes zero sense. You see things differently? -- well, show me your model and let's talk about *that*!

So no, there is no *rational* reason for having a power hierarchy. What is the cause, then, for our persistent failure to act rationally? -- well, I have some ideas, but that's a different question.

<sup>**1**</sup> *And no, there are no reasons **why** we would **have to** struggle to understand what the other person **actually meant** to say. After all, words are mere references to the concepts in our minds, and those concepts describe the same reality, or people just like ourselves.*

<sup>**2**</sup> *If there's a better definition of **existential crisis**, I would love to hear it. And if there is a better example of **insanity** than responding to it by "agreeing to disagree" -- I would definitely like to hear that too.*

<sup>**3**</sup> *While our primary motivation (for casually sharing our opinions with others and welcoming others to share theirs with us) might be a rather selfish hope that they might prove us wrong {and thus, patch a gap in our understanding for free), helping others is just as important -- because their mistakes can hurt anyone, and because keeping them up to date knowledge-wise makes them better equipped to return the favor in the future*

<sup>**4**</sup> *... which too should be dealt with in the same way we act towards people in general -- with fairness, respect, dignity, and compassion*

Comment: What about knowledge hierarchies, teacher-student? How do you know the essence of being a good human? What about value judgements, like on capital punishment or abortion, can't we disagree in valid ways based on our paradigms?

Comment: 1. A teacher seeks to be proven wrong just like everyone else... even better if by his own student. 2. I know like everything else -- by having a model and getting every testable predictions out of it (so far, everything checks out). 3. Knowledge is *the only* virtue. I nerver heard about "paradigms", but feel free to educate me.

Comment: What about an engineer where a thorough grounding is needed to work safely? And are you familiar with the Dunning-Kruger effect?

Comment: yeah yeah... here's some insider info for you: Dunning-Kruger = PhD depression + noise (like duh!... of course idiots think they know everything <== that's Socrates, btw)

Comment: the depression part was, actually, covered earlier -- "The learning of many things does not teach understanding; otherwise, it would have taught Hesiod and Pythagoras, and again Xenophanes and Hecataeus." <== i don't know them

Answer (score 0):

All relationships between individuals should be **conscious**, not behaviouristic and/or based on some external system of values (POV). There are indeed persons of a higher degree of consciousness - more mature individuals with larger life experience. They are natural leaders in any human society.

A human society based on consciousness where the best benefit of the whole has been recognized as stemming from the **natural self-interest** of human beings. That means that as long as individuals work for themselves, the whole of society will gain maximum growth.