# How to justify retributive punishment?

Tags: ethics

It is said that retributive punishment is an expression of a misguided, sadistic sensibility—one that delights in controlling others, violating their human rights and making them suffer. When punishing someone, our sympathy is transformed into a shared feeling to perform acts of torture. We use the person who committed an immoral act or crime as a means to our pleasure

How do we justify such sadistic torture? Is it ever moral to make someone suffer? And why?

Comment: Everything up to the last sentence is a baseless accusation that assumes the answer to the question. In any case, there are plenty of places you can go where no governing authority provides a reliable threat of retribution - probably within a few miles of your home, in fact. Just wander around at night until somebody mugs you, and you'll know you've found utopia.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the arguments for revenge and retribution?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/94137/what-are-the-arguments-for-revenge-and-retribution)

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of [loaded question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question)? One example is "do you still beat your wife?", your post is another, and those are off-topic here. In the unlikely case that you are interested in the actual ethics of the practice you already pre-branded as misguided and sadistic, here is [SEP, Retributive Justice](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/justice-retributive/).

Answer (score 1):

When a maniac who killed and raped is put into jail where he definitely suffers I don't enjoy the fact of his suffering (though someone can) but I am glad he is not roaming the streets of my town. Moreover if he suffers there because the law is violated (like prison rules) I won't be glad cause it means there is corruption in law enforcement and tomorrow I or my close friends may suffer from it as well in another situation.

Unfortunately the science is still not at that point when you can reprogram the brain of a dangerous criminal. So the society protects itself by isolating him/her. What do you offer to do instead?

Comment: "*One bad turn deserves another. So does a good turn.*" -Aristotle? This is just like the **Tit For Tat** strategy in Game Theory, which worked out to be the only stable method of cooperation. It is basically a Law.