# Is there any philosophical work on profanity?

Tags: reference-request

Is there any philosophical work about profanity, f-words, dirty words?

Comment: We discussed 'What are some arguments against insulting being illegal' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/81070/what-are-some-arguments-against-insulting-being-illegal/81077#81077 & 'Censorship: Why should a word be censored when it is being discussed?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/94381/censorship-why-should-a-word-be-censored-when-it-is-being-discussed/94519#94519

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bad Words: Philosophical Perspectives on Slurs](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/bad-words-philosophical-perspectives-on-slurs/), essays ed. by David Sosa.

There's a chapter in Questions About Language: Do people swear because they don’t know enough words? From which, this summary [Why do people swear?](https://www.routledge.com/blog/article/questions-about-language-why-do-people-swear),  gives a nice introduction to ideas about purposes of Swearing.

There's an IAI interview: [Rebecca Roache On Swearing and Philosophy](https://iai.tv/articles/on-swearing-and-philosophy-an-interview-with-rebecca-roache-auid-832), & she did a Philosophy Bites podcast episode [What, if anything, is wrong with swearing?](https://philosophybites.com/2015/03/rebecca-roache-on-swearing.html), and a [Practical Ethics: On Swearing](http://blog.practicalethics.ox.ac.uk/2015/02/on-swearing-lecture-by-rebecca-roache) lecture at Oxford.

A paper: [The Philosophy of Cursing: Heidegger and Wittgenstein on Being-in-the-World and the Language Game of Cursing](https://www.zacharyfruhling.com/philosophy-blog/the-philosophy-of-cursing-heidegger-and-wittgenstein-on-being-in-the-world-and-the-language-game-of-cursing).